# Why does C++11 not support name lookup like this?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

```
struct A
{
    enum InnerEnum { X };

    A(InnerEnum x)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a(X);
}
```

The compiler complains: `error C2065: 'X' : undeclared identifier`

The compiler knows what the constructor's parameter type is, so when I pass X as the argument, the compiler should know it is a valid argument.

I know this is not ADL(Argument-dependent Name Lookup, also known as Koenig Lookup), but I think it's useful and pretty handy. Because I don't have to write as follows:

```
A a(A::X);
```

I think the ADL rule should be generalized to such a case.

Am I right?

Comment: This is like the inverse of ADL... FDL (function dependent lookup).

Comment: Have you considered how this would apply when you also have a local variable named `X`? And regardless, the way I read your question, you're saying this is invalid C++, and are asking whether the C++ standard should change. This is the wrong place for that.

Comment: Thanks, hvd. You gave us a convincing rationale.

Comment: If you're asking if the standard is wrong, no; *that's why its the standard.* That you find it decidedly inconvenient is a separate issue. Your constructor requires an `A::InnerEnum` value for a parameter. That enum definition is in the `A` *namespace scope* and requires resolution when accessed outside of said-same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function calls in C++ are subject to function overload resolution. Overload resolution is driven by the argument types. I.e. the language "works" specifically in that direction: *from* argument types *to* specific version of the function with the given name.

You are proposing to introduce a reverse process - argument type deduction based on function name. This will not work in general case. It might work in cases when there's only one candidate function (as in your example), but, again, in is contrary to principles that work in the general situation when the function is overloaded.

Of course, the situation will get even more complicated when name lookup on unqualified name `X` can see something else named `X` in addition to your `A::X`. I think it can easily get very counterintuitive.

Comment: I understand the complexity arguments which apply in general. So, maybe not in general but for some reason I think this would be particularly useful for `enums`. Since they often serve as arbitrarily named options for functions.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the ADL rule should be generalized to such a case.

No thank you.

C++ has its share of (nasty) surprises (which other language do you know requires `explicit` as a keyword?), and I don't see enough merit in your example to add to this list of unexpected language rules hindering my code in unexpected situations.

If you find the additional typing entailed in class-name followed by the two colons as too much effort, then surely the general baroque nature of C++ syntax should have put you off by now?